# Will it be possible to omit the type name when initializing C++2a class non-type template arguments?

Tags: c++, c++20

The following does not compile on GCC 9.1 (which supports class non-type template parameters)

```cpp
struct S { int i; };

template<S s>
struct T {};

int main()
{
    T<{0}> x{};
}
```

The compiler reports `error: could not convert '{0}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'S'` despite the template argument `s` being of concrete type `S`.

```cpp
T<S{0}> x{};
```

works as expected, but will C++2a allow the concrete type name `S` to be omitted, as is the case in other parts of the language?

Comment: what about adding an implicit constructor that converts int to S? ` constexpr S(int in) :i(in){}`

Comment: @Hui That does indeed allow this simple example to compile, but I don't think it would interact nicely with designated initializers, for example. Saying that, GCC 9.1 does appear to allow designated initializers in this case, however I think it is using an initializer list instead of doing what you'd expect it to. That is, T<{.i=0}> compiles, but it also compiles when changing .i to any arbitrary identifier such as T<{.a=0}>. Is that a GCC bug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> will C++2a allow the concrete type name S to be omitted?

**No**.

> #### [`[temp.arg.nontype]/2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.nontype#2.sentence-1)
>
> A template-argument for a non-type template-parameter shall be a converted constant expression (`[expr.const]`) of the type of the template-parameter.

In `T<{0}>`, `{0}` is not an `S`: it is not an expression of the type of the template-parameter (`S`). `{0}` would be an [*initializer list*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#def:initializer_list) (in a context where it would be allowed).

---

Bonus:

> #### [`[dcl.init.list]/4`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#1.sentence-4)
>
> List-initialization can occur in direct-initialization or copy-initialization contexts; list-initialization in a direct-initialization context is called direct-list-initialization and list-initialization in a copy-initialization context is called copy-list-initialization.

No initialization occur for template-arguments (unless when it does, see [`[temp.arg.nontype]/1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.nontype#1)).

Comment: I mean sure, but why not just say that the grammar doesn't allow a braced init list as template argument :)

Comment: @Rak *facepalm*

Comment: This is CWG2450 (which is not publicly available yet); the intent is to allow it, probably even in C++20 modes.  (There will also be an issue to define template parameter object initialization, since it’s non-trivial for objects of class type.)

Comment: Thank you @Davis for the update. I'll update my answer as soon as this document is published.